# GraphStage with shape of 2-in 2-out

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I need to write a custom `GraphStage` that has two input ports, and two output ports. This `GraphStage` will allow two otherwise independent flows to affect each other. What shape could I use for that? `FanOutShape2` Has two outputs and `FanInShape2` has two inputs, but how can I have a shape that has both? Somehow combine (inherit from) both? Use `BidiFlow`? Make my own?

Comment: For reference, also posted here: https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/graphstage-with-shape-of-2-in-and-2-out/4160

Comment: Depending on what that "affect each other" is, making your own may be only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this myself, since this has been solved by the helpful guys on discuss.lightbend.com, see https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/graphstage-with-shape-of-2-in-and-2-out/4160/3

The answer to this question is to simply use `BidiShape`. Despite the otherwise revealing name, the logic behind a `BidiShape` has to be by no means bi-directional (it's obvious in retrospect, but I was thrown off by this).

Some code that can be used for reference if anybody is in a similar situation, where they have to do something based on two inputs, with the possibility to push to two outputs:

```
class BiNoneCounter[T]() extends GraphStage[BidiShape[Option[T], Option[Int], Option[T], Option[Int]]] {
  private val leftIn = Inlet[Option[T]]("BiNoneCounter.in1")
  private val rightIn = Inlet[Option[T]]("BiNoneCounter.in2")
  private val leftOut = Outlet[Option[Int]]("BiNoneCounter.out1")
  private val rightOut = Outlet[Option[Int]]("BiNoneCounter.out2")
  override val shape = BidiShape(leftIn, leftOut, rightIn, rightOut)

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
    private var grabNextPush = false

    val inHandler = new InHandler {
      override def onPush(): Unit = {
        if (grabNextPush) {
          (grab(leftIn), grab(rightIn)) match {
            // do stuff here
          }
        }
        grabNextPush = !grabNextPush
      }
    }

    val outHandler = (inlet: Inlet[Option[T]]) => new OutHandler {
      override def onPull(): Unit = {
        pull(inlet)
      }
    }

    setHandler(leftOut, outHandler(leftIn))
    setHandler(rightOut, outHandler(rightIn))
    setHandler(leftIn, inHandler)
    setHandler(rightIn, inHandler)
  }
}
```

Can be used like this:

```
        sourceOne ~> bidi.in1
                     bidi.out1 ~> sinkOne
        sourceTwo ~> bidi.in2
                     bidi.out2 ~> sinkTwo
```